# Review on diophantine equations

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, arithmetic-geometry

Solving diophantine equations was a classical motivation for development of mathematics. As far as I know methods used there are rather diverse: at least some hard arithmetic geometry and diophantine approximations are among them though there are sophisticated elementary approaches. Could you recommend any good (possibly complete) reviews reflecting the current state of this field? Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: While I can't, I know modular arirhmetic can be used.   Mod can be looked at as weaker form of equality. But every true equality in the integers, automatically fits Mod.

Comment: Here's a reference for a book.   
https://books.google.fr/books?id=faYE_41prOkC&pg=PR11&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Then there are few references on this link.  
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133764/is-there-an-online-encyclopedia-of-diophantine-equations-oede

Comment: Thank you for references! In my view all these sources tend to concentrate on elementary methods e.g. there is no discussion of Faltings's theorem and advanced arithmetic geometry.